# passing python data to javascript in web2py

Tags: javascript, python, json, xml, web2py

Here is my problem. I have the following function

```
def index():
    rows=db(db.mylist).select()
    return dict(rows=rows)
```

so whenever I reload the the front view index I want to retrieve rows from the database and display the data to the user in a list

```
{{for(r in rows)}}
    li.innerhtml={{=rows.task}}
{{pass}}
```

Obviously, this is not the right way to do it. I think I have to use json and XML.

This is the table I am using

```
db.define_table(
   'mylist',
   Field('task', 'string')
)

<div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading center " style="color: black; font-style: inherit">
                 <form>
                 Task:
                <input name="name" id="task"  />
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick=add(),ajax('{{=URL('default','insert_task')}}',['name'])  >add</button>
                     </form>

             </div>

              <div class="panel-body center">
                  <ul id="list" class="list-group">  </ul>
              </div>

         </div>

     </div>
 </div>


var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var lastId=0;
function add()
    {
        if(!isBlank(document.getElementById("task").value)) {


            var iCon = document.createElement('div'); //create a div container
            var dbtMenu=document.createElement('div');
            var li = document.createElement("il");  //create a list-element
            var closeSpan = document.createElement("span"); //create a span for badge attribute
            var ClickListState=0;

            dbtMenu.setAttribute("class","container");
            //dbtMenu.appendChild(dropDownList);
            li.setAttribute('id',lastId); // set an attribute for id
            iCon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"; // image for remove button
            closeSpan.setAttribute("class", "badge"); //create a new attribute for span
            closeSpan.appendChild(iCon); // put it in the span set
            iCon.addEventListener("click",function(){var element=document.getElementById(li.getAttribute('id'));
                                                    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);}); //functionlity
            li.innerHTML = document.getElementById('task').value;
            var value=document.getElementById('task').value;
            var pass= document.getElementById('task').value;
            li.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item hover-yellow");
            li.addEventListener('click',function() {if(ClickListState==0){li.style.backgroundColor="red"; ClickListState++;}
                                                    else {li.style.backgroundColor="white"; ClickListState--; }});
            li.appendChild(closeSpan);
            lastId++;
            ul.appendChild(li);

        }
    }

function update()
    {
            {{for r in rows:}}
            var iCon = document.createElement('div'); //create a div container
            var dbtMenu = document.createElement('div');
            var li = document.createElement("il");  //create a list-element
            var closeSpan = document.createElement("span"); //create a span for badge attribute
            var ClickListState = 0;

            dbtMenu.setAttribute("class", "container");
            //dbtMenu.appendChild(dropDownList);
            li.setAttribute('id', lastId); // set an attribute for id
            iCon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"; // image for remove button
            closeSpan.setAttribute("class", "badge"); //create a new attribute for span
            closeSpan.appendChild(iCon); // put it in the span set
            iCon.addEventListener("click", function () {
                var element = document.getElementById(li.getAttribute('id'));
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            });
           // var t ={#{=XML(response.json(r.task))}}
                    li.innerHTML = "t";
            var value = document.getElementById('task').value;
            var pass = document.getElementById('task').value;
            li.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item hover-yellow");
            li.addEventListener('click', function () {
                if (ClickListState == 0) {
                    li.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    ClickListState++;
                }
                else {
                    li.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    ClickListState--;
                }
            });
            li.appendChild(closeSpan);
            lastId++;
            ul.appendChild(li);

            {{pass}}

    }
    update();
```

Comment: I would suggest reading the web2p documentation before proceeding with your app.

Comment: Hello Anthony, thanks for the reply. I am doing both reading the documentation and coding the app, but I just don't have a good memory to retain all the information. I can retain the workflow of a web2py, but I still forger some technical aspects in the code. Your reply in my previous thread was very useful. It solved my problem

Comment: I still need help. How do we use rows in javascript?

Comment: @Anthony I actually need to get the element "task" from the table and put it in a li.innerhtml in javascript –

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how the templates work. All Python code (i.e., inside the `{{...}}` delimiters) gets executed on the server before the page is delivered to the browser. So, your Python code cannot interact with Javascript code (which is executed in the browser after the full page has been processed by web2py). In other words, you cannot have a Python loop that runs some Javascript code within the loop. You will need to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Anthony I've updated the thread with the the main idea.  I am basically trying to write and update function that retrieves data from the database and put it in a to-do list whenever the user refreshes the whole page. ADD() will display the data locally and update() will display the data whenever the user reloads the page. I don't feel like your claim is completely true. I looped through the elements in the database with the loop I put in thread and then I replaced the li.innerhtml with any string to see if it corresponded to the number of elements in the database. It turns out it does

Comment: @Anthony I will clean up the code once I figure out how to solve the problem

Comment: I'm not sure to what "claim" you are referring, but everything in my previous comment is certainly true. The Python loop in your view is being executed *on the server*, not in the browser. If you look at the HTML source of the page in your browser, you will see that the `{{for r in rows:}}` loop has produced an exact copy of the entire body of your `update()` function once for every time through the loop. Surely that is not what you want. You should write the entire Javascript function in *Javascript*. Just use web2py to generate a data structure to pass to that function.

Comment: You might be better off asking on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py), as there probably needs to be some back and forth discussion to get you up to speed on how things work.

Comment: @TheMathNoob from your edit i think you want to insert task into database and also want to append task to tasklist UL without refreshing the page, I edited my answer and added few resources that will help you to achieve this. It is still not clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1):

Read the basic syntax for template language in web2py [here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#forin)

You want this:

```
<ul>
    {{for row in rows:}}
        <li>{{=row}}</li>
    {{pass}}
</ul>
```

Other solution can be, build the complete list in controller function using [html helpers](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Built-in-helpers) and pass it to view

```
def index():
    rows = db(db.mylist).select()
    my_list = [row.task for row in rows]
    task_list = UL(*my_list)
    return dict(task_list=task_list)
```

And in the view just do:

```
{{=XML(task_list)}}
```

> [XML](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#XML) is an object used to encapsulate text that should not be
>   escaped.

I will suggest you to go through these 2 examples: [Image blog](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#An-image-blog)  and [Simple wiki](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#A-simple-wiki)

**EDIT:**

From your edit, I think you want to add new task using form and wanted to add the list without refreshing the page.

Read [Ajax form submission](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax#Ajax-form-submission), also related ajax example is given in [simple wiki app](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#A-simple-wiki)

```
<!-- Views/index.html-->
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<form id="task_form">
     Task:
    <input name="name" id="task"  />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Add" />
</form>

<div id="target"> {{=XML(task_list)}}</div>


<script>
jQuery('#task_form').submit(function() {
  ajax('{{=URL("default", "insert_task")}}',
       ['name'], 'target');
  return false;
});
</script>
```

--

```
# Controller

def index():
    rows = db(db.mylist).select()
    my_list = [row.task for row in rows]
    task_list = UL(*my_list)
    return dict(task_list=task_list)

def insert_task():
    """an ajax callback that returns a <ul>"""
    task_name = request.vars.name
    db.mylist.insert(task=task_name)
    rows = db(db.mylist).select()
    my_list = [row.task for row in rows]
    task_list = UL(*my_list)
    return task_list
```

Comment: how would you do it in javascript?

Comment: I actually need to get the element "task" from the table and put it in a li.innerhtml in javascript

Comment: @TheMathNoob, you will need to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need to set li.innerhtml via Javascript rather than just create the `<li>` elements via Python (given that you are looping through all the list elements on the server before any Javascript even gets executed in the browser)? If you really need to process everything via Javascript, then just use web2py to write some Javascript data structure into the page and handle all the processing with Javascript.

Comment: @Gaurav Vichare I will try to explain it one more time. The ADD() function will display the data locally. The ajax function will store the data in the database once the add button is pressed. If we reload the web-site all the data will go away visually but will remain in the database. You know that reloading the whole page is equivalent to calling index in the controller, so this controller will return all the rows in the database and these rows will be passed in a function called update in javascript which will keep the data visually to the user. update() will always be called

Comment: @TheMathNoob updated my answer once again, so now index controller willl return all task and view will display it, if user adds new task using form then ajax call to  `insert_task` function will add that value in database and also will return new updated task list which will be inserted in target div. If u refresh the index page then anyway all the task will be returned and will shown in list format. there is no need of add() and update() js functions. Let me know if this solve your issue or not

Comment: you can also just append newly added task to existing list on successful insert into db, i am replacing complete list with updated one.

Comment: Yes that's what I am doing. I am displaying the data to the user and storing data in database in two different branches. I am about to try your way, but the problem is that I have to do other things to the list such as adding delete buttons, hovering etc. How would you do that with a returned list form python?

Comment: @TheMathNoob add `id` and `class` attribute to each `li`.  Using class you can give hover effect. Make ajax call on click of delete to delete the task, id can be used to decide which row to delete. On success of ajax call delete row from view using javascript. I will suggest you to build list in view using `for` loop using templating syntax, check first paragraph of answer

Comment: how do I do that. This is the list I have to handle {{=XML(task_list)}}. It's not in javascript, so how can I manipulate the list in this format?

Comment: First go thorugh the chapter [the view](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views)  that will answer most of your question. If u don't find the solution post your question in [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py). Can't add more comments here, stackoverflow warned me due to long discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this to convert a python list of strings to a javascript array of strings:

```
{{def print_js_array(left_side, pylist):

  wrap_quotes = map(lambda a: "'{}'".format(a), pylist)

  comma_separated = "" if not pylist else reduce(lambda a,b: "{}, {}".format(a,b), wrap_quotes)

  return "{} = [{}];".format(left_side, comma_separated)
}}

{{=SCRIPT(
  ""
  + print_js_array("var un_pythoned", status_filter_options))
}}
```

Which given a python list `['', 'Not Started', 'Running', 'Finished', 'Failed']` results in (html):

```
<script><!--
var un_pythoned = ['', 'Not Started', 'Running', 'Finished', 'Failed'];
//--></script>
```

Making the array available to subsequent scripts. You could probably write something similar to print a dictionary as json.